# How to clear folder contents on application close

Tags: c#

i want to delete all items from my custom made folder, but i want to do it when the application closes as the user no longer needs a handle on these files anymore.

Where in the c# code should i write such a method? For example is there a application.shutdwon event or something :$

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Winforms has an [`ApplicationExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx) event.

WPF has an [`Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) event.

You can write your cleanup code in the event handler.

Comment: I thihk he should use same clean up code in the unhandled exceptions handlers too.